# How to bind to a StaticResource with a Converter?

Tags: wpf, xaml, staticresource, converters

I want to use a `Converter` to change the value of a `StaticResource` before assigning it to a property. Is there a way to simulate a `Binding` that will just set the value of the `StaticResource` after converting it?

Something like `{Binding Value={StaticResource myStatic}, Converter={StaticResource myConverter}}`?

Answer (score 71, accepted):

This works:

```cs
<TextBox Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource myStatic}, 
                        Converter={StaticResource myConverter},
                        Mode=OneWay}" />
```

Note that you have to bind one way, because the binding requires a path attribute otherwise. This makes sense, as otherwise the binding would have to replace the whole resource...

Comment: For properties, which probably won't change at runtime from XAML side this `Mode=OneWay` isn't required, e.g. for `Grid.Row`. Anyway - I finally got ridden of magic numbers from XAML in favor of enums, thanks!