# Bind position of an element on canvas

Tags: c#, wpf, canvas, binding, ivalueconverter

I have a canvas (rectangle) where I draw a point. When I move mouse, this point changes its position, but I want to change not only position in the canvas, but also data in my model (namely 2d vector).

Can I bind position of a point on a canvas to my vector using XAML? Maybe I should create a ValueConverter, but I don't know how to get reference to canvas in the function

```
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType,
                      object parameter, CultureInfo culture) {
   ...
}
```

Comment: please refer the mentioned link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623343/how-to-bind-to-a-staticresource-with-a-converter

Answer (score 2):

Ok, finally I did the following.

I add an ellipse as a child of canvas and bind its `left` and `top` values to components of vector in my model. Here's XAML code:

```
<Canvas x:Name="MyCanvas" Background="Black" MouseMove="MyCanvas_MouseMove">
  <Ellipse x:Name="PointEllipse" Canvas.Left="{Binding MyVector2D.X, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" Canvas.Top="{Binding MyVector2D.Y, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, Mode=TwoWay}" >
  </Ellipse>
</Canvas>
```

And when I move mouse, I do the following:

```
private void MyCanvas_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.LeftButton == MouseButtonState.Pressed)
    {
        var pt = e.GetPosition(MyCanvas);

        PointEllipse.SetValue(Canvas.LeftProperty, pt.X);
        PointEllipse.SetValue(Canvas.TopProperty, pt.Y);
    }
}
```